# How to change Jacoco output directory on Android?

Tags: android, jacoco

On my Android project, Jacoco coverage report file is generated in below directory.
"/app/build/reports/jacoco/~"

I wanna know how to change Jacoco output directory => such as "/build/~".

If there is any option, please let me know.
Thank you. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the latest [jacoco plugin document](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:configuring_the_jacoco_plugin), here is an example to configure the `reportsDirectory`:

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.9"
    reportsDirectory = layout.buildDirectory.dir('customJacocoReportDir')
}
```

By the way, for some old jacoco plugin versions, the old configuration name is `reportsDir`, such as:

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
}
```

> Table 1. Gradle defaults for JaCoCo properties

| Property | Gradle default |
| --- | --- |
| reportsDirectory | layout.buildDirectory.dir("reports/jacoco") |